# Regarding fundamental concept of inequality

Tags: inequality

How the in equality $$x^2<2$$ 
means $$x\in \left(-\sqrt 2,\sqrt2\right) ?$$
So, from the inequality $x^2\lt 2$ what i did in the next step is, i took root over on both sides i.e. i left with $x\lt±\sqrt2$ which certainly means $x<-\sqrt2 $ or $x<\sqrt2$  
 which in notations looks like $(-\sqrt2,-\infty)\bigcup(\sqrt2,-\infty)$
=> $(-\sqrt2,-\infty)$.
 I am unable to get where i am getting wrong, Waiting for valuable insights!

Comment: You edited the question to $x^2\color{red}{<}2$, right? All answers seem to assume that $x^2>2$. The reasoning to solve your new inequality is similar though.

Comment: I had never experienced nor expected this fast response from community therefore within minutes i edited my typing errors.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful with inequalities and signs: For example, if $a < b$ (e.g. $1 < 2$), then $-a > -b$ (e.g. $-1 > -2$), i.e. the direction of the inequality flips. In your case, if you carry out the steps very slowly and step by step, you get the following:
\begin{align*}
  x^2 < 2 &\iff \sqrt{|x|^2} < \sqrt{2} \\
          &\iff |x| < \sqrt{2} \\
          &\iff x < \sqrt{2} \ \ \text{ and }\  x > -\sqrt{2} \\
          &\iff x \in (-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})
\end{align*}

*Edit*: Changed inequality sign as in the edited question

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the inequality $x^2>2$ means that $x\in\left(-\infty,-\sqrt2\right)\cup\left(\sqrt2,\infty\right)$. In fact\begin{align}x^2>2&\iff\sqrt{x^2}>\sqrt2\\&\iff|x|>\sqrt2\\&\iff x\in\left(-\infty,-\sqrt2\right)\cup\left(\sqrt2,\infty\right).\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

What have you done is taken square root and concluded $x>\pm \sqrt{2}$ Now the thing here is that it should be $x>\pm \sqrt{2}$

So now the $2$ cases possible-

1. $x>\sqrt{2}$ - Yes true
2. $x>-\sqrt{2}$

But one minute RHS has been multiplied by $-1$ so it should be $x<-\sqrt{2}$

One simple way to solve is take square root and conclude $|x|>\sqrt{2}$. So it will simplify to $x>\sqrt{2}$ and $-x<-\sqrt{2}$

Another thing to note here is that $x\in\left(-\infty,-\sqrt2\right)\cup\left(\sqrt2,\infty\right)$ should be the answer

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what set $x$ is taken from. This information is missing from your question.